# If Else Statement, got twice the Output

Tags: java, if-statement, irc

In my IRC Bot, as soon as someone types !highfivetest the bot gives out a message twice.
Is something wrong with my if-else?

Arry String;

```
public String[] moderatoren = {"furby1987","furbybot"}; // Moderatoren
```

CmdOutput;

```
        if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("!highfivetest")){
            for(int i2 = 0; i2 < moderatoren.length; i2++){  
                if (sender.equals(moderatoren[i2])){
                    sendMessage (channel, "!highfive");
                }else{              
                    sendMessage(channel, "Nur eingetragene Moderatoren haben Zugriff auf diesen Befehl. Sry <3"); 
                }
            }
        }
```

Usually, i just type it that way;

```
            if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("!highfivetest")){
                for(int i2 = 0; i2 < moderatoren.length; i2++){  
                    if (sender.equals(moderatoren[i2])){
                        sendMessage (channel, "!highfive");
                    break;
                    }else{              
                        sendMessage(channel, "Nur eingetragene Moderatoren haben Zugriff auf diesen Befehl. Sry <3"); 
                    break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

But are the breaks really needed? just a bit irritated right now :-)

Greetings!

Comment: What is `moderatoren.length` ?

Comment: its an Array String,    public String[] moderatoren = {"admin1","admin2"}; // Moderators

Comment: Does `moderatoren` contain unique entries?

Comment: Well if the array contains 2 values then obviously the for loop will output it twice. You should feel really awkward right about now.

Comment: Hmm okay :P So how i can rewrite it to go through the list checking for the sendername without output the message each time?

Comment: You would probably utilize a boolean to flag special cases like in the answer proposed by @Robin Krahl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message should be sent *outside* the `for` loop.  Otherwise it will be printed for every moderator that did not send the `!highfivetest` message.  To simplify the code, you could change the array of moderators to a `List` and then use the `List.contains` method.

Example 1:

```
boolean vonModeratorGesendet = false;
for (int i2 = 0; i2 < moderatoren.length; i2++) {
    if (sender.equals(moderatoren[i2])) {
        vonModeratorGesendet = true;
        // you could also send "!highfive" from here
        break;
    }
}
if (vonModeratorGesendet) {
    sendMessage (channel, "!highfive");
} else {
    sendMessage(channel, "Nur eingetragene Moderatoren haben Zugriff auf diesen Befehl. Sry <3");
}
```

Example 2:

```
List<String> moderatorenListe = Arrays.asList(moderatoren);
if (moderatorenListe.contains(sender)) {
    sendMessage (channel, "!highfive");
} else {
    sendMessage(channel, "Nur eingetragene Moderatoren haben Zugriff auf diesen Befehl. Sry <3");
}
```

Example 2 is the better option.  Instead of converting the array to a `List`, you could also use a `List` at all the time (that's what I would do).

Answer (score 1):

Your `if-else` is fine, the problem may be in `for` loop or somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

replace the breaks with continues, it's a loop you're running.

```
            if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("!highfivetest")){
            for(int i2 = 0; i2 < moderatoren.length; i2++){  
                if (sender.equals(moderatoren[i2])){
                    sendMessage (channel, "!highfive");
                continue;
                }else{              
                    sendMessage(channel, "Nur eingetragene Moderatoren haben Zugriff auf diesen Befehl. Sry <3"); 
                continue;
                }
            }
        }
```

That should work, continue is the c++ syntax for it as I'm unfamiliar with java but if you hunt there will be a similar line in the java language if it isn't continue.

Comment: it's because it is outputting the message each time it runs to for loop (that's how the for loop works), so I'm presuming your moderatoren.length is an array with 2 pieces of data in it? you need to break out of the loop as soon as it's completed the first one

Comment: That won't fix the issue

Comment: Since this is an if/else statement these specific `continue`s are pretty much useless since if it enters the `if` it will not enter the `else`

Comment: you're right, my bad. It actually sounds like it's working fine now that I've read some further comments, he has an array of two moderators and it's just outputting the message for both of them(?)

Comment: Nah, the for loop is only used to iterate over the moderator array, and since the array contains 2 moderators it iterates twice. When a moderator sends this command he only receives one message since he/she appears in the array only once. The problem is when a regular user sends this command, the loop iterates over the moderator array twice and since it doesn't find the regular user among the moderators it outputs the regular user message each time for each moderator check, thus twice.